# static const variable of multiple object instances in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, constants, instance-variables, static-members

I have a static const variable declared in the m file of a ClassA

```
static NSString * const myConstString = @"a string value";
```

So myConstString is a constant, and is not accessible outside of the file.

My question are:

1. If I have multiple instances of ClassA, will the myConstString be alloced just once?
2. If I use `#define myConstString @"a string value"`, will myConstString be alloced just once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The static variable has absolutely nothing to do with the class.  It has "file scope" and there will only be one.
2. Do not do that.